# What is the intuition behind P(Y=4) in this example?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In my text book I have the following question:
Given two fair dice, one blue and one red.
Each die has two faces of the same number $\lbrace 1,\ 2,\ 3\rbrace$.
We toss the two dice until they both match.

Let $X$ be a RV that counts how many times we threw the dice.

Let $Y$ be a RV that is the sum of the first toss.

1. What is the distribution of $X$?
2. What is $P(Y=4)$?

For 1 I deduced that the distribution is a geometric distribution.

My question is for 2:

Why can't we deduce that: the probability of getting a 4 is 1/9 ?

My reasoning is that for the first toss we need 2 and for the second toss we also need a 2, each with a probability 1/3 of happening.

However, the solution in the textbook relies on the law of total probability and that $Y$ depends on $X$, therefore we sum $$P(X=1,Y=1) + \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} P(X=k,Y=4).$$

Why is my intuition wrong here?

Comment: I think the first thing to clarify is: what is the first toss you are calculating the sum of? Could you give an example?

Comment: Your question 2, as posed, is too easy, so I expect that Y is supposed to be the sum (over all the times we threw the dice) of the number on the blue die, or something similar.  As asked, $P(Y=4) = \frac13$ because of the nine possibilities, $(1,3), (2,2), (3,1)$ give $Y=4$ and it has nothing to dow with $X$.

Comment: For example: For each toss we throw both of them together, the first toss we threw both of the dice, blue die is 3 and the red is 1, Y will be 4, then we keep tossing until a match happens (Y doesn't change after the first toss).

Comment: @MarkFischler That is what i thought at first but when I saw the answer in the textbook I thought my method was wrong, thank you.

Comment: I think the answer would be correct if $Y$ was the sum of the last toss

Comment: How can $Y$ ever be equal to $1$?

Comment: @amd I suspect a typo, since the answer is otherwise correct (just overly complicated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo aside, the answer is correct, just needlessly complicated.

Let $T_n$ be the result of the first toss (an ordered pair).

Now $\mathsf P(Y{=}4)$ is the probability that the sum of the first toss is 4 when either that happens on the first toss (when the die match) or later (so the die don't match on the first toss).

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y{=}4) &= \mathsf P(Y{=}4, X{=}1)+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \mathsf P(Y{=}4,X{=}k)\\[1ex] &={{\mathsf P(T_1{=}{\small(2,2)})} +{\mathsf P(T_1{\in}\{{\small(1,3),(3,1)}\})} {\sum_{k=2}^\infty\mathsf P(T_k{\in}\{{\small (1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}\})} {\prod_{j=2}^{k-1}\mathsf P(T_j{\notin}\{{\small(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}\})}}\\[1ex] &= \dfrac 19+\dfrac {2}9\cdot \dfrac 13\sum_{k=2}^\infty \left(\dfrac 23\right)^{k-2}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac 19+\dfrac 29\cdot\dfrac 33\\[1ex]&=\dfrac 13\end{align}$$

---

> Why is my intuition wrong here?

You only evaluated the case where both die showed 2; they might also show $(1,3),(3,1)$.

$\mathsf P(Y{=}4) =\mathsf P(T_1\in\{{\small(1,3),(2,2),(3,1)}\})=\tfrac 39$